# Adding a search method in jTable (jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-jtable

It's hard to implement a search method in a jTable.
Codes:

generaterecords.php:

```
<?php
$page_title = "Generate Reports";
require_once('template/header.php');
require_once('template/navmenu.php');
require_once('template/content-top.php');
?>
<div class="filtering">
<form>
<select name="year" >
<option value="0000">Year</option>
<?php
for($i=date('Y'); $i>2012; $i--) {
echo '<option value="'.$i.'"'.'>'.$i.'</option>'."\n";
} 
?>

</select>
<select name="month">
<option value="0">Month</option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" id="LoadRecordsButton">Load records</button>
</form>
<div id="PeopleTableContainer" style="width: 850px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

        //Prepare jTable
        $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'Payment Records',
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            sorting: true,
            defaultSorting: 'payment.paymentdate ASC',
            actions: {
                listAction: 'payment.php?action=list'
            },

            fields: {
                paymentid: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                lname: {
                    title: 'Last Name',
                    width: '20%',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false
                },
                fname: {
                    title: 'First Name',
                    width: '20%',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false

                },
                mname: {
                    title: 'Middle Name',
                    width: '20%',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false
                },
                paymenttype: {
                    title: 'Type',
                    width: '20%',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false
                },
                paymentdate: {
                    title: 'Date',
                    width: '20%',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false
                },
                totalrate: {
                    title: 'Total Rate',
                    width: '20%',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false
                },
                paymentamt: {
                    title: 'Amount',
                    width: '20%',
                    create: false   
                },
                balance: {
                    title: 'Balance',
                    width: '20%',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false
                }
            }
        });

        //Load person list from server
        //$('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load');

        //Re-load records when user click 'load records' button.
        // Backup
    $('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load', {
            year: $('#year').val(),
            month: $('#month').val()
        });
    }); 



    //Load all records when page is first shown
   // $('#LoadRecordsButton').click();

    });

</script>
<br>
<br>
<?php
// footer
require_once('template/footer.php');
?>
```

payment.php:

```
<?php
include_once ('database_connection.php');
try
{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","kureido","tnx4standinstillwanker");
mysql_select_db("kureido", $con);
//Getting records (listAction)
if($_GET["action"] == "list")
{
    //Get record count
    $offresult = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS OLRecordCount FROM official;");
    $offrow = mysql_fetch_array($offresult);
    $allresult = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS AllRecordCount FROM lodger;");
    $allrow = mysql_fetch_array($allresult);
    $resresult = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS ResRecordCount FROM reservation;");
    $resrow = mysql_fetch_array($resresult);
    $recordCount = $allrow['AllRecordCount'] - $offrow['OLRecordCount'] - $resrow['ResRecordCount'];

    $year = "";
    $month = "";
    if (empty($_POST['year']) && empty($_POST['month']))
        $year = $month = "";
    else
    {
        $year = $_POST['year'];
        $month = $_POST['month'];
    }

    //Get records from database
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT payment.paymentid, lodger.ssn, lodger.lname, lodger.fname, lodger.mname, payment.paymenttype, payment.paymentdate, payment.totalrate, payment.paymentamt, payment.totalrate - payment.paymentamt AS balance FROM payment, lodger WHERE lodger.ssn = payment.lodger_ssn AND YEAR(paymentdate) = '" . $_POST["year"] .  "' AND MONTH(paymentdate) = '" . $_POST["month"] . "' ORDER BY " . $_GET["jtSorting"] . " LIMIT " . $_GET["jtStartIndex"] . "," . $_GET["jtPageSize"] .";");

    //Add all records to an array
    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    //Return result to jTable
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $recordCount;
    $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
//Creating a new record (createAction)
/*  else if($_GET["action"] == "create")
{
    //Insert record into database
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO people(Name, Age, RecordDate) VALUES('" . $_POST["Name"] . "', " . $_POST["Age"] . ",now());");

    //Get last inserted record (to return to jTable)
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE PersonId = LAST_INSERT_ID();");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    //Return result to jTable
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    $jTableResult['Record'] = $row;
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
} */
//Updating a record (updateAction)
else if($_GET["action"] == "update")
{
    //Update record in database
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE official SET room_code = '" . $_POST["room_code"] . "', appliancerate = '" . $_POST["appliancerate"] . "', monthlybal = '" . $_POST["monthlybal"] . "' WHERE lodger_ssn = " . $_POST["ssn"] . ";");

    //Return result to jTable
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
//Deleting a record (deleteAction)
else if($_GET["action"] == "delete")
{
    //Delete from database
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM official WHERE lodger_ssn = " . $_POST["ssn"] . ";");

    //Return result to jTable
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
else if($_GET["action"] == "view")
{
}

//Close database connection
mysql_close($con);

}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
//Return error message
$jTableResult = array();
$jTableResult['Result'] = "ERROR";
$jTableResult['Message'] = $ex->getMessage();
print json_encode($jTableResult);
}

?>
```

Sometimes the server returns errors. Any ideas on how to get this fixed? generaterecords.php is the client side while payment.php is the server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load', {
        year: $('#year').val(),
        month: $('#month').val()
    }); 
     });
  //remove your comments .. the code below is for running the function above when loadrecords button is clicked
   $('#LoadRecordsButton').click();
```

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow. Can you provide some details on why this is the answer to this question?

Comment: Please provide some sort of explanation as to why this is answer solves the question

Comment: Kath is literally re posting the code the OP has posted.  This is also the jQuery code given by [jTable documentation](http://www.jtable.org/demo/filtering)